# C++11 algorithms with multiple predicates

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, predicate

Functions such as `std::find_if` from the `algorithm` header are really useful, but 1 serious limit for me is the fact that I can only use 1 predicate for each call to `count_if`.

For example given a container like an `std::vector` I would like to apply, at the same time, with the same iteration of `find_if`, multiple predicates; there is something in the standard library that makes this possible while keeping this functional approach ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just combine them with a lambda:

```
std::find_if(begin(vec), end(vec),
    [](elem_t val) {
        return f1(val) || f2(val);
    });
```

Comment: oh, it's much simpler than what I expected

Comment: but with this approach the results for different predicates end up going in the same output, what if I would like to dispatch the result to a specific object for each predicate ?

Comment: @user2485710 - to do that you write your own algorithm.

Comment: @user2485710: it's probably easiest to use `std::copy_if` for each distinct destination, but that involves multiple passes over the source container so it might be more efficient to use a `for` loop with `if (predicate1(val)) dest1.push_back(val); else if ...` lambda.  (If you care about performance, always benchmark with your data.)

Comment: @user2485710: I'm not sure what you mean. What output? The results of the predicates go to the algorithm for its decision making process about what to do. In the case of `find_if`, that means either terminating if the result is `true`, or continuing on if the result is `false`.  Do you have a concrete example of the kind of thing you want to do? Because I may have a solution.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you have a person that does the job for you and you give him: 1 container, 3 predicates, 3 buckets, 1 algorithm ( `find`, or `copy`, or ... ), and only 1 chance to iterate over the container; so you have to apply 3 predicates at each container position, at the same time, and each predicate has its own bucket to store the result.

Comment: @user2485710 and what if a single element satisfies more than 1 predicate? do you want to copy it to all the corresponding buckets?

Comment: @TemplateRex each predicate only refers to 1 single bucket, so yes, if the predicate is `true`, pass the result to the associated bucket.